# rails update_all interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, update-all

I have a database with a lot of pets.
I am looking to update the 'name' attribute by changing it's case.
I have tried:

```
Pet.update_all(:name => Pet.name.upcase)
Pet.update_all(:name => name.upcase)
Pet.update_all(:name => :name.upcase)
Pet.update_all(:name => "#{name.upcase}")
```

but all of those return:

- "PETS" for every name
- "NAME" for every name
- "NAME" for every name
- invalid syntax

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are refering to an own attribute inside of the update attribute you won't be able to do this without iterating. An option coul be:

```
Pet.all.each {|x| x.update(name: x.name.upcase)
```

Another option:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "UPDATE pets SET name = UPPER(name)"
```

Comment: No, that's not how scoping works. `self` is not in a function, so it'll always be the current class's instance

Comment: Fixed an added a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do it Rails way:

```
Pet.update_all(:name => "UPPER(name)")
```

Comment: That just don't work in Rails 4.1. The result is the column "NAME" to be the string "UPPER(name)"

Comment: wrong answer. it will give result as: `irb(main):005:0> Pet.pluck(:code)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT "pets"."name" FROM "pets"
=> ["UPPER(name)", "UPPER(name)", "UPPER(name)", "UPPER(name)", "UPPER(name)", "UPPER(name)"]`

Answer (score 0):

`Pet.update_all('"name" = Upper("name")')` works in Rails 5.2